# Sequelize N-M association doesn't recognize the include model

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, many-to-many

I am trying to do a many-to-many assocition with sequelize but I constantly having the same error without reason...
Here is the error I get : `SequelizeEagerLoadingError: User is not associated to UserTool!`
I searched on the web and my code is corresponding to many right answers that I found.
The M-M association goes like this : `User-UserTool-Tool`, `UserTool` is the bridge table between `User and Tool`

Here is the following code :

**Model User - User.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var db = require('../../config/database');

const User = db.define('User', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'User'
});

module.exports = User;
```

**Model Tool - Tool.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var db = require('../../config/database');

const Tool = db.define('Tool', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
}, {
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'Tool'
});

module.exports = Tool;
```

**Model UserTool - UserTool.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var db = require('../../config/database');

const UserTool = db.define('UserTool', {
    userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    toolId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    status: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    active: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
}, {
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'UserTool'
});

module.exports = UserTool;
```

**Main.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var db = require('../../config/database');

const User = require('./User');
const Tool = require('./Tool');
const UserTool = require('./UserTool');

User.belongsToMany(Tool, { through: UserTool });
Tool.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserTool });

module.exports = {
    User,
    Tool,
    UserTool
}
```

And then when I try to do a `findAll()` with an `include`, I get the error mentionned previously.

Here is the code of the findAll with the include

**Find.js**

```
const {User, UserTool} = require('./Main');
exports.FindAllUsers = async function (params) {
let message;

await UserTool.findAll({
    where: {
        userId: params.userId
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: User
        },

    ]
});
```

Comment: First of all, do you really need to create that "bridge" manually? Let sequelize handle it. You can simply remove the join table (which is UserTool model in the code) and after the belongsToMany calls sequelize will handle it for you.

Comment: To ease the comprehension of my code, I didn't put all the attributes in the UserTool model, but I think that I need to create it manually because these attributes needs to be in the UserTool bridge table, I updated my code so you can check. But these fields in the bridge table helps me to track a certain state of these N-M associations.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, if you want to query all users. Simply use the following method:

```js
const result = await User.findAll();
```

If you want to query the user with `id = 1` and all tools for that user, using:

```js
const result = await User.findAll({
  where: { id: '1' },
  include: [{ model: Tool }],
});
```

sequelize will query the appropriate `Tool`s for `User` based on the join table `UserTool`. Eager loading needs both sides(`User` and `Tool`) of the model are established associations(`belongsToMany`). `UserTool` doesn't establish associations with `User`, so you can't use `include` options, that's why sequelize throw that error.

Comment: So, how can solve the problem and establish an association between UserTool and User so that we can actually get a list of records with not only the user.id(s) and get the other User attributes/columns?